# How to convert graphic to JSON string

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I draw the circle on the map. The circle tool is taken from ArcGIS API for JavaScript draw tool. How can I convert that circle into JSON string.

Comment: which version of ARcGIS-JS-API are you using? 
Can you provide a code snippet, so everyone knows better what you say? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a reference to the map and its layers collection, it will something like this:

```
app.map._layers.drawGraphics_poly.graphics[0].toJson();
```

Notes:

- "app." might not be necessary in your case, depending on the context of the map object
- "drawGraphics_poly" might not be the name of the graphics layer holding the circle in your case, look through the _layers collection to find the right one
- [0] assumes you just have one circle drawn; if multiple it'll be somewhere in that array of graphics.